# What has sun.plugin.javascript become in JDK 7?

Tags: java, version, sun

I have some code importing sun.plugin.javascript.JSContext. What has happened to the package in JDK7?

Comment: What version of 1.7 are you using, and what platform are you working on? That will be what the answer depends on.

Answer (score 0):

In my Windows Java 7 (update 15) installation

```
find . -name "*jar"|xargs grep sun.plugin.javascript.JSContext
Binary file ./jre/lib/plugin.jar matches
```

So the class is in  ./jre/lib/plugin.jar. This is most likely platform and version dependant. Please see Brant's comment.